# Yii2 inline validation inside ActiveRecord Model

Tags: validation, activerecord, yii2

Here is the Model code with inline validation rule.

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;

class Country extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'country';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ...other rules...
            ['pan_no', 'checkPanCardUsers', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'skipOnError' => false]
        ];
    }

    public function checkPanCardUsers($attribute, $params)
    {
        ...some condition ...
        $this->addError($attribute, 'custom error message');
    }
}
```

Controller code

```
public function actionSomeAction()
{
    $model = new Country();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) {
        if($model->validate()) {
            $model->save();
        }
    }
    return $this->render('country', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

But the validation is not working.

Comment: can you show your controller code? because I guess its more a problem of how you have created your model.

Comment: hmm strange i couldn't see an error from the quick look. I have no clue why you get the error that the addError() function isn't defined.
What happens if you log the class inside your model on your custom validation? just to be sure that it is the correct class etc. The problem is normal yii validation rules also using this addError function to add the errors (or at least i am pretty sure they do). So these should also have the same issue.

Comment: Is your condition returning a correct result? You can use `die("Blablabla")` to check.

Comment: if you would remove the condition completly and only use the addError what happens then?
Or try to debug with `die($this->className());`

Comment: @BHoft I am not getting any error but the validation is not working.

Comment: How do you see that validation isn't working? Is you inline method called or not?

Comment: if you just have the addError call in that function there "must" be an error when you submit the form. Either that or you don't have the function name in the rules. Also if you add a die('whatever'); and the function is called the page handling must stop. If this is not the case the function isn't called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure just use the following in your rules then your function will be called.

```
['pan_no', 'checkPanCardUsers', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'skipOnError' => false]
```

and just add your error in your function when your condition is wrong.

```
public function checkPanCardUsers($attribute, $params)
{
    //...some condition ...
    if (!$this->$attribute !='test')
        $this->addError($attribute, 'custom error message');
}
```

Hmm strange it works on my test flawlessly..

Check how you have created your model e.g. on create action:

```
$model = new ModelName();
```

Comment: updated the question check now. Its not working also

Comment: Thanks my code was OK but I was missing id so whole validation was not working.