# yii2 only numbers and + for string

Tags: php, yii2

I want to be able to write only `numbers` and `numbers` with `+` at the end in the field, for example `10+`

As far as I understand, it is impossible to do this for an integer

It turns out that I need to make the field a string and add validation where only `numbers` and `+` can be used, or what is better?

And how do I do it in `rules()`, I only know how to add a max value:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['number'], 'string', 'max' => 11],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Try to use regular expression match rule, like this one: 
```[['number'], 'match', 'pattern'=> '/^[0-9]+\+?$/'],```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate type in the rule is a `string`.

The you have to add a custom validation rule (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32840337/3286903 for an example).

In your validation function,

- check for the pattern `'/^[0-9]+\+?$/'` with `preg_match()`
- define an error message

and you're done.